# Interface Builder XIB Error - Unable to write to path

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode5

I get sporadic, occasional one-time errors that often clear up on a second attempt
at building, after cleaning or holding down the Option key and clicking Product -> Clean Build Folder.

Is there anything I can do to avoid errors like this one which seem to be tied to a single .xcproj (XCode Project) that is my main xcode project. It never happens on a new or empty product, and always seems to fail on the same Nib file (`MainWindow-iPhone.nib`).

full error message:

```
  /Users/user/XCodeWork/iPhoneDev/MyAppSourceFolder/en.lproj/MainWindow-iPhone.xib: 
  Compilation failed. Unable to write to path:        
  /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPPNAME-
  dudnhxzgpqtcnqcgaguirvkhmvco/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/
  MYAPPNAME/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyAppname.app/
  en.lproj/MainWindow-iPhone.nib
```

I've had a look at folder permissions and I have full rights to the Intermediates folder
paths shown above.  Just incase there is some `sudo` like crap happening inside XCode's build, I set the path to everyone having Read & Write permission, but that does not fix it.

The above error happens during regular debug build, as well it occurs during Archive operations, and often it prevents me from completing the archive step.

I am using XCode 5.0.1 (5A2053) on OS X Mavericks 10.9 (13A603)

Comment: I hope someone figures this out.  My co-developer and I both have this same problem.  The worst is when it happens during Archive right before a release since doing another archive takes so long, and even that one can fail!

Comment: It happens MOST often when changing from build-for-debug to build-during archive, but also happens frequently when you change which device you are targeting (build for running on your real iphone, then switch to building for the iOS 7 simulator).

Comment: I have the same problem, exactly... I can run on a device but it's almost impossible to archive.

Comment: Same issue here. Sometimes, it can happen several times in a row (six or seven times in a row, earlier today). It doesn't seem to happen if I clean before building, although I may be wrong. I expanded the error log last time and it said the first (of maybe three very similar) "underlying error" was:


    The file “runtime.nib” doesn’t exist.

Comment: Happened with Xcode 7.3 too, nice job apple !!

Comment: I also have this issue using Xcode 10.3 :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution!! (At least it has worked for me).

For every xib's that we've problems, in the right panel go to the first tab, "Interface Builder Document" -> "Builds for" and select "iOS 7.0 and Later". My old configuration was "iOS 4.3 and Later".